# If something is 1 mile long and is being filmed from an unknown distance

Tags: geometry

If something is 1 mile long and is being filmed from an unknown distance is it possible to calculate that distance?
For example objects enters frame certain point on picture and then x time later the end of it arrives at same point and you know the object is 1 mile long.

Comment: Consider the case that the object is a straight line segment 1 mile long, and the point of view is colinear with that line segment...

Comment: You would need to know some additional information. For example, if the half-mile point on the object had a distinguishing mark then you could find the range to both ends and to the midpoint using a pinhole camera just by measuring the two angles separating the midpoint from either end. I had to do this exact calculation in 1980 when using a single camera to find the range to and normal vector to a surface bearing a distinguishing mark (Marking parts to aid robot vision, NASA TP 1819)

Answer (score 0):

You will need another object in frame of known length and distance or the focal length of the lens.

Comment: Also you need to know the angle the object makes with your direction of viewing.